# how to specify what content to show on templates literals

Tags: javascript, html, css, template-literals

I'm using template literals to display some fetched data, I've manage to display everything I need to the frontend, however some of the content is hidden as is meant to be togglable, however , I'm kind of lost as to how can I link each specific button to the specific part of the html template that needs to be displayed.

What would be the best way to do this?

how can I be able specify to display a specific div on click of a specific button?

I've got to the point to get the value of the button clicked, and the idea was to link this to the specific id of the div I want to display, but I'm lost, any help would be great on how can I tackle this.

I'm just trying to toggle the display from none to block.

```
const link = './data copy.json';

// const container = document.getElementById('.item-container');
fetch(link)
  .then(res => {
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);

    data.forEach(gun => {
      const template = `
    <div class="ticket ticket-${gun.ticket}">
    <div class="id card"><p>${gun.gunId}</p>
  </div>
    <div class="location card">
      <p class="gun-id">${gun.location}</p> 
    </div>
    <div class="description card">
      <button class="view" value="${gun.gunId}"onclick="modalForm()">Details</button>
      <div  class="modal" id="modal-${gun.ticket}">
      <form class="modal-content" id="" data-value="${gun.gunId}"onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); validateForm();">
        <div class="form-header">
          <h1 id="" class="gun-form-name">${gun.gunId}</h1>
          <span id="" class="close" onclick="closeModal()">×</span>
          <span id="" class="back-arrow fa-lg" type="button" onclick="goBack()" role="button" aria-label="Go Back Button"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-left"></i>
           </span></div>
        <section class="main-content">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="wrapper">
                  <h3>${gun.gunId}</h3>
                    <div class="img">

                        <img class="gun-image"src="gun image.PNG" alt="test">
                        <div class="btn-overlay">

                        <button class="overlay-btn btn-1" value="${gun.partId.lightPipeId}"type="button">${gun.partId.lightPipeId}</button>
                        <button class="overlay-btn btn-2" value="${gun.partId.lightbugId}"type="button">${gun.partId.lightbugId}</button>
                        <button class="overlay-btn btn-3" value="${gun.partId.batteryId}"type="button">${gun.partId.batteryId}</button>
                        <button class="overlay-btn btn-4" value="${gun.partId.triggerId}"type="button">${gun.partId.triggerId}</button>
                        <button class="overlay-btn btn-5" value="${gun.partId.triggerPcb}"type="button">${gun.partId.triggerPcb}</button>
                        <button class="overlay-btn btn-6" value="${gun.partId.triggerSpring}"type="button">${gun.partId.triggerSpring}</button>
                        <button class="overlay-btn btn-7" value="${gun.partId.grayCable}"type="button">${gun.partId.grayCable}</button>
                        <button class="overlay-btn btn-8" value="${gun.partId.powerCableid}"type="button">${gun.partId.powerCableid}</button>
                        <button class="overlay-btn btn-9" value="${gun.partId.stockPcb}"type="button">${gun.partId.stockPcb}</button>
        
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="details">
                           <p class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi ut iure molestiae dolores commodi amet reiciendis recusandae voluptatem porro cumque fuga excepturi eum necessitatibus, vel, assumenda alias voluptas debitis veniam.</p>
                           <p class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi ut iure molestiae dolores commodi amet reiciendis recusandae voluptatem porro cumque fuga excepturi eum necessitatibus, vel, assumenda alias voluptas debitis veniam.</p> 
                           <p class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi ut iure molestiae dolores commodi amet reiciendis recusandae voluptatem porro cumque fuga excepturi eum necessitatibus, vel, assumenda alias voluptas debitis veniam.</p> 
                           <p class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi ut iure molestiae dolores commodi amet reiciendis recusandae voluptatem porro cumque fuga excepturi eum necessitatibus, vel, assumenda alias voluptas debitis veniam.</p> 
                           <p class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi ut iure molestiae dolores commodi amet reiciendis recusandae voluptatem porro cumque fuga excepturi eum necessitatibus, vel, assumenda alias voluptas debitis veniam.</p>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn">
                        <button class="close-ticket"type="button">Close Ticket</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </section>
        
      </form>
    </div>
  
    </div>
  <div class="close-bt card">
    <button class="delete-button"id="${gun.gunId}">Close</button>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>`
      document.getElementById('item-container').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', template);

      const modal = document.querySelectorAll(`#modal-${gun.ticket}`);
      const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.view').value;
      console.log(btns);
      for (let i = 0; i < modal.length; i++) {
        let child = modal[i];
        console.log(child);
      // switch()
    };
  });
    document.getElementById('open-tickets').innerHTML = data.length;
    document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(button => {
      const modal = document.querySelectorAll(`#modal-${gun.ticket}`);
console.log(modal);
      button.addEventListener('click', () => {
          const fired_button = button.value;
          alert(fired_button);
          modal.style.display = "block";
          // modal2.style.display = "none";
      });

  });
})
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

this is the output:
[image]

Comment: You can use separate variables of Boolean type to toggle the values and link them with their respective div.

Answer (score 0):

```
const modal = document.querySelectorAll(`#modal-${gun.ticket}`);
```

`modal` is a NodeList[], use `querySelector` instead to return the element.

I'm pretty sure `gun.ticket` is also undefined, since you're outside your `data.forEach` loop.

Try something like this instead (untested):

```
document.querySelectorAll('button.view').forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', => {
    const modal = document.querySelector(`#modal-${button.getAttribute('value')}`);
    modal.style.display = 'block';
  });
});
```